# run process every few days even if you've exited ssh session

Tags: python

I have been trying to write a python script that will continue to run even if I have closed the ssh session. It needs to be able to execute a command in Linux every few days and when the commands process stops, wait a few days and execute the same command. I thought it would be pretty simple and easy for me to do, but it turns out I can't do it... ***Please help***

Comment: @Brain Kemp,  Trying to understand You need to execute some script on remote server, even the host computer lost/disconnect ssh session?

Comment: This looks like a two part question.  Writing the script and scheduling it to run.  What part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

Use your system's cron facility to run commands on schedule.

Run `crontab -e` to edit your crontab, then add something like

```
0 0 */2 * * /usr/bin/python my_script.py
```

where [`0 0 */2 * *` means "00:00" every other day-of-month](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_*/2_*_*).